# Problems with javascript validation in PHP document

Tags: php, javascript, validation, email, passwords

I have this .php document where you can register on a webshop. I want to add javascript validation to it, but the site is made of .php completely, so no html head and body tags. Normally you can put the javascript source in the head tag, but in the .php you can't. (or at least i don't know how)
When testing the code, the javascript document seems fine, but when i put it in the .php document it gives certain errors about (") and ('). When i try to link to the seperate javascript document, the code doesn't seem to work at all.

(i've added the whole php page) Php document begin:

```
<?php

include 'header.php';
include 'menu.php';

    echo '
```

```
function checkEmail(myForm) 
{
    if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(registration.emailAddress.value))
    {
    return (true)
    }
        alert("Invalid E-mail Address! Please re-enter.")
        return (false)
}

function validatePwd() 
{
    var invalid = " "; // Spatie mag niet
    var minLength = 6; // Minimaal 6 tekens
    var pw1 = document.registration.password.value;
    var pw2 = document.registration.passwordConfirm.value;
// Beide velden gelijke waarde
    if (pw1 == "" || pw2 == "") 
    {
        alert("Please enter your password twice.");
        return false;
    }
// Minimale lengte variabele
    if (document.registration.password.value.length < minLength) 
    {
        alert("Your password must be at least " + minLength + " characters long. Try again.");
        return false;
    }
// spatiegebruik variabele
    if (document.registration.password.value.indexOf(invalid) > -1); 
    {
        alert("Spaces are not allowed.");
        return false;
    }

    else 
    {
    if (pw1 != pw2) 
        {
        alert ("You did not enter the same new password twice. Please re-enter your password.");
        return false;
        }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
    }
}
```

```
        <div id="main">

    <form name="registration" action="registerconfirm.php" method="post" id="form" onSubmit="return validatePwd()">


        <h2>Personal Information</h2>


        <fieldset class="login_register">


            <label for="firstName" class="form">First name:</label> 

                <div class="registrationForm" id= "firstNameCheck"></div>

                    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="register_first_name"/>


            <label for="lastName" class="form">Last name:</label>

                <div class="registrationForm" id="lastNameCheck"></div>

                    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="register_last_name"/>


            <label for="email" class="form">E-mail:</label>

                <div class="registrationForm" id="emailCheck"></div>

                    <input type="text" name="emailAddress" id="register_email"/>


        </fieldset>


        <h2>Login Information</h2>

        <fieldset class="login_register">


            <label for="password" class="form">Password:</label>

                <div class="registrationForm" id="lastNameCheck"></div>                 

                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>


            <label for="passwordCheck" class="form">Confirm password:</label>

                <div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divPassCheck"></div>

                    <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm"/>


            <input type="submit" class="button" value="SUBMIT"/>

        </fieldset>

    </form>

</div>

';

include 'footer.php';
```

?>

and the Javascript code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function checkEmail(myForm) 
{
    if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(registration.emailAddress.value))
    {
    return (true)
    }
        alert("Invalid E-mail Address! Please re-enter.")
        return (false)
}

function validatePwd() 
{
    var invalid = " "; // Invalid character is a space
    var minLength = 6; // Minimum length
    var pw1 = document.myForm.password.value;
    var pw2 = document.myForm.passwordConfirm.value;
// check for a value in both fields.
    if (pw1 == '' || pw2 == '') 
    {
        alert('Please enter your password twice.');
        return false;
    }
// check for minimum length
    if (document.myForm.password.value.length < minLength) 
    {
        alert('Your password must be at least ' + minLength + ' characters long. Try again.');
        return false;
    }
// check for spaces
    if (document.myForm.password.value.indexOf(invalid) > -1) 
    {
        alert("Sorry, spaces are not allowed.");
        return false;
    }

    else 
    {
    if (pw1 != pw2) 
        {
        alert ("You did not enter the same new password twice. Please re-enter your password.");
        return false;
        }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: Why do you allow only two and three letter TLDs? Why do you ban `+` characters in the front half of the email address?

Comment: It gives errors where the ' are used. I replaced them with " . It also gives an error at else { if (pw1 != pw2). "Syntax error else"

Comment: @quentin

because I was told to do so, it is for a class assignment ;)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is executed in the client's browser (aka, client-side), PHP is a server-side language.

Unless you plan on writing a JS interpreter for PHP, you can't run JS from PHP.
A better option would be to re-write the JS in PHP.

---

Unless you're having trouble including the file, then you'll just have to edit a:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="myJSFile.js"></script>` tag into your `header.php`.

So:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="myJSFile.js"></script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things: you can add a `<script>` tag anywhere you like. The attribute `language`, though, doesn't really exist, but that's not *that* important. All the same, it should be `<script type="text/javascript">`.
If your site is the output of (a bunch of) PHP scripts, why not simply `echo` the script?

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/script.js"></script>';
```

Or, in the header file:

```
    echo '<title>Title</title>';
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var script ='just add it here';
</script>
<?php
    echo '</head>';//continue php
```

There's nothing preventing you to do this, either.

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHPs HEREDOC Syntax to output the function.
http://www.php.net/manual/it/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc